# Android: Flip animation with transformation matrix

Tags: android, animation, matrix, 3d

I'm still fairly new to android, but I was hoping to figure some stuff out about animations.

I was trying to build a view flip animation, but it became one of the sketchiest things I've seen right off the bat. I tried this:

Animation in XML:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:valueTo="360"
    android:propertyName="rotationY" >
</objectAnimator>
```

Animation application in Java:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = (ObjectAnimator)AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(contextReference, R.animator.card_left_flip);
animation.setTarget(passView);
animation.setDuration(2000);
animation.start();
```

This produced a very terrible animation that would crop my views, rather than add perspective.

Is there a good way to perform 3D animations in android, preferably with matrices, without having to use OpenGL?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look this from the Api Demos:
[Rotate3dAnimation](http://code.google.com/p/apidemos/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.java?r=6)

The way I've used this is to animate 180 degrees, swap the image in a ImageView and then rotate back. It works pretty well.

Comment: Okay. I've come across that before, but then I lost it. I don't think I understood it before, but I'll check it out and get back to you!